# get difference value from 2 table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables named `T1` and `T2`. Both of the tables have a column in common called balance. How can I get the difference between the two sums of the two tables.

Example:

```
T1

balance
-------
100
50
```

The sum for `T1` would be 150 (100 + 50)

```
T2

balance
-------
100
200
```

The sum for `T2` would be 300 (100 + 200)

So I would like the output to give me the result 150 (sumT1-sumT2).

Comment: Doesn't seem too difficult. What have you tried?

Comment: @sstan i have try code below but it returns error  #1582 - Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'ISNULL' in mysql

Comment: @AntonPrioHutomo:see updated

Comment: @AntonPrioHutomo that is why you should remember you put MySQL in the tag when you first make the question :).  From a quick google it appears that MySQL does not contain 'ISNULL()'.  Apparently instead it is 'IFNULL()'.  So try that instead.

Comment: @Cody360c it solved sir thanks for advice

Comment: @AntonPrioHutomo No problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just sum and select from tables ..

```
select (select ifnull(sum(balance),0) from t2)-(select ifnull(sum(balance),0) from t1) as balance
```

Comment: its ok but if one of the column has no value/null, the result become null too  @TheGameiswar

Comment: i have try your code to MySql but the error said
#1582 - Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'ISNULL' i have 1 row both of the table

Comment: please tag your question relevant to RDBMS you use,i have updated answer specific to mysql

Comment: solved sir, just change the "isnull" to "ifnull" in mysql thanks